# NpgsqlParameter value is passed to stored procedure but one list object is missing in all item in the list

Tags: c#, .net-core, stored-procedures, npgsql

Model:

```
 public class OtherItems
    {
       .....
    }

public class Category 
{
   public string categoryName {get; set } = "";
   ......
   public List<OtherItems> lstOtherItems {get; set } = new List<OtherItems>();
}


    public List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();
    categoryList = ...FN RETURN VALUE...;
```

Inputs:

```
new NpgsqlParameter("CategoryList", NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb| NpgsqlDbType.Array) { Value = categoryList , DataTypeName = "arjsnCategory"}
```

**categoryList** serialized structure is

```
[{}, {..., 'lstOtherItems': [...] }, ....]
```

All the list items contain **'lstOtherItems'** (another list).

Problem:

After passed to stored procedure, Inside procedure when inspected receiving procedure parameter '**arjsnCategory**' the 'lstOtherItems' which i expected inside every items of *arjsnCategory* is missing. **not coming in to procedure **.

Is there any way to handle this missing problem?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your question. Please post a minimal code sample as well as the actual error you're seeing.

Comment: I agree with @ShayRojansky - this question is hard to follow. If I had this problem, I think the first thing I would try is passing in an array instead of a list, since your NpgsqlDbType is Array.